# Cannot read a file from Downloads folder on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have text files with a custom extension. I have deployed one with my Delphi FMX application to the Documents folder, and this one loads fine using `TStringList.LoadFromFile(Path)`. The path is:

`/data/user/0/com.embarcadero.[appname]/files/[filename]`

I then try to load a file from the following path:

`/storage/emulated/0/Download/[filename]`

`FileExists(Path)` returns true, indicating that the file does exist. However, it fails in `TStringList.LoadFromFile(Path)`.

I assume that this is some permissions issue. However, I have checked that 'Read external storage' is enabled in the Delphi project options under 'Uses Permissions', so the manifest should have that included. Are there any other permission settings required for this location?

Note that I'm testing on a Huawei P10 with Android 8.

Comment: Do not only use file exists() but also file canRead() first. You did not tell how your file landed in that location.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure of a canRead function in Delphi. I'm new to Android development. Can you explain why how they got in that location could make a difference? I put them there myself by direct transfer from my laptop via USB cable. So I didn't actually download them. They do show up in my phone's file manager app in the Download folder.

Comment: Then they do not belong to your app. Your app can only see that they exist but has no permission to read them in the classic way as you have seen. Well on Android 11+ devices. Use SAF ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select the file.

Comment: First thing to do is consider whether you can avoid using the shared folders. Once you run it on later versions of Android, it becomes more difficult. For Android 8, it's likely just an issue of requesting the permissions at runtime (as well as having them in the manifest).  Please see: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Android_Permission_Model. In your case, the permission will be READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: The file type I'm reading are rotator files (.rot). This is an old format of 3D model in the form of a wire mesh. Coordinates and colours are written in a text file. Although it's an old format and not used much these days, there are still a lot of them around on old websites. I'd like people to be able to download these files and then load them in my app. So I don't think I can avoid using the shared folders, unless I include a web browser in my app, which seems overkill. There must be a way to use files from shared folders as many apps use the shared photo library for example. I will read up

Comment: @DaveNottage, I have checked READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as mentioned in my question. I guess I still have to request permission at runtime though, using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or similar.

Comment: I can now finally load the files after using PermissionService.RequestPermissions for ReadExternalStorage, as per the Object Pascal/Mobile Snippets/CameraRoll sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The files load after using PermissionService.RequestPermissions for ReadExternalStorage, as per the Object Pascal/Mobile Snippets/CameraRoll sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
  {$IF DEFINED (ANDROID)}
  var FStorage := '/storage/emulated/0/RAH Download';
  {$ELSEIF DEFINED (MSWINDOWS)}
  var FStorage := ExpandFileName(GetCurrentDir) + PathDelim + 'Download';
  {$ELSE}
  ShowMessage('Not Support';
  Exit;
  {$ENDIF}

  if not DirectoryExists(FStorage) then begin
    if not CreateDir(FStorage) then
      Exit;
  end;
```

===========================================================

```
  var HTTP := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    var Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      HTTP.Get(FURL, Stream);
      Stream.SaveToFile(FStorage + Pathdelime + 'FileName');
    finally
      Stream.DisposeOf;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.DisposeOf;
  end;
```